# Do votes on duplicate comments do anything?

Tags: discussion, automatic-comments

If you vote to close a question as a duplicate, the site auto-generates a "Possible duplicate of..." comment.

If such a comment has already been generated for someone else, and you go in to close as a duplicate, and choose the same post as the other person, it auto-upvotes their generated comment.

Does this upvote on the comment do anything special? Does the upvote itself count as me also voting that it's a dupe? I know votes on "normal" comments are purely aesthetics, but are generated comments different?

If I upvote a generated duplicate comment, is that the same as me manually going in and voting to close it as a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but if you vote to close it as a duplicate you will automatically upvote the comment. Not having it go both ways is important as the voting on a comment threshold is much lower than the vote to close.

Voting to close is a lot more serious than then voting for a comment. I myself while looking at the android app accidentally have upvoted comments before. I'd rather not have fat thumbing a comment leading to a question being closed for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 2):

No.

If you want to vote to close something as a duplicate, you have to actually do it in the review queues or by clicking on "close" and going through the close pop-up.

Upvoting it is just like upvoting any other comment... it means you agree with it and nothing else.